# Consuming a JAX-WS in a Mule ESB flow

Tags: soap, jax-ws, mule, esb, mule-studio

I want to consume a JAX-WS service method. the methode is named find and accept a String as argument.

this the Mule flow :

```
<flow name="InvokeAWebServiceFlow1" doc:name="InvokeAWebServiceFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\input" pollingFrequency="3000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="File to String"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client port="douaneWSPort"   serviceClass="WSDL.DouaneWS" doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" operation="find"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\output" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

I put a argument into a file, in this exampl the argument is "ctr1" after i put the file into the inbound endpoint, after that the file is transformed into a String and goes to the JAX-WS client, finally the respponse is written into an output file.

when I run the flow I get as an output :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <ns2:find xmlns:ns2="http://douane.ws/">
  <id>ctr1</id>
 </ns2:find>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

the output is the SOAP the request instead of the expected SOAP Response, that should be somthing like:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:findResponse xmlns:ns2="http://douane.ws/">
         <return>
            <quality>medium</quality>
            <price>150</price>
            <idProd>ctr1</idProd>
         </return>
      </ns2:findResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope
```

>
 .

The error generate is

```
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'invokeawebservice'                          +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2013-05-14 11:13:15,024 [[invokeawebservice].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\input\input.txt
INFO  2013-05-14 11:13:15,155 [[invokeawebservice].InvokeAWebServiceFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.component.simple.LogComponent: 
********************************************************************************
* Message received in service: InvokeAWebServiceFlow1. Content is:             *
* '<soap:Envelope                                                              *
* xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:find  *
* xmlns:ns2...[100 of 173]'                                                    *
********************************************************************************
INFO  2013-05-14 11:13:15,184 [[invokeawebservice].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.2917880'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-05-14 11:13:15,184 [[invokeawebservice].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.2917880'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-05-14 11:13:15,200 [[invokeawebservice].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\output\14-05-13_1368522795199.xml
WARN  2013-05-14 11:13:15,261 [[invokeawebservice].InvokeAWebServiceFlow1.stage1.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://douane.ws/}DouaneWSService#{http://douane.ws/}find has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected wrapper element {http://douane.ws/}find found.   Expected {http://douane.ws/}findResponse.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:799)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:280)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:375)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:235)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:125)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:122)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:192)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:185)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:184)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR 2013-05-14 11:13:15,271 [[invokeawebservice].InvokeAWebServiceFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Unexpected wrapper element {http://douane.ws/}find found.   Expected {http://douane.ws/}findResponse.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Unexpected wrapper element {http://douane.ws/}find found.   Expected {http://douane.ws/}findResponse. (org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault)
  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor:106 (null)
2. Unexpected wrapper element {http://douane.ws/}find found.   Expected {http://douane.ws/}findResponse.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:144 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected wrapper element {http://douane.ws/}find found.   Expected {http://douane.ws/}findResponse.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:799)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the webservice you want to consume is hosted, let's say at http://domain.com/ws , than your configuration should look like this:

```
<flow name="InvokeAWebServiceFlow1" doc:name="InvokeAWebServiceFlow1">
<file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\input" pollingFrequency="3000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
<file:file-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="File to String"/>
<cxf:jaxws-client port="douaneWSPort"   serviceClass="WSDL.DouaneWS" doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" operation="find"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://domain.com/ws" />
<echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
<file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\output" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

You can find more informations on the topic [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF)