# How to pass a file as SOAP request to Mule SOAP client to consume service

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, mule, mule-studio

I have a flow which is exposing a webservice :-

```
<flow name="ServiceFlow" doc:name="ServiceFlow">

<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP"/>

<cxf:jaxws-service  serviceClass="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData"  doc:name="SOAP"/>

<component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/>

</flow>
```

This web service have a operation **insertDataOperation** which takes all the input from SOAP request and insert it in Database...
My SOAP request is as follow :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:insertDataRequest>
         <v1:Id>311</v1:Id>
         <v1:Name>ttttt</v1:Name>
         <v1:Age>56</v1:Age>
         <v1:Designation>eeeee</v1:Designation>
      </v1:insertDataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I have another web service client flow which is consuming  this webservice and the flow is :-

```
<flow name="ClientFlow" doc:name="ClientFlow">
 <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_Global" doc:name="File"  path="E:\backup\test">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="SoapRequestInsert.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="File to String"/>
<cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="SOAP" serviceClass="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData" operation="insertDataOperation" port="MainDataPort" />
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Now here I am trying to consume the webservice by using a file inbound endpoint and passing the SOAP request in the file **SoapRequestInsert.xml** .. But the issue is that I don't get any error but the data is not inserted in database.. I checked the log .. where I found it enters the insert method of webservice implementation class but it doesn't get the input value ... Please help ... I have taken the reference from the following :- [Consuming a JAX-WS in a Mule ESB flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539303/consuming-a-jax-ws-in-a-mule-esb-flow)

But It's not working .. what should I do to make it consume successfully and insert into DB ??? Pls help

Comment: What does `com.test.services.schema.SOAPOptionalData.AddAttachmentMessageProcessor` do? What is the format of the file?

Comment: It is used for adding custom attachment... Please ignore that line .. I forgot to remove that .. The service is actually working fine and I have tested with SOAPUI ... The issue is with Client flow ...

Comment: Updated the flow .. removed that line of code :-com.test.services.schema.SOAPOptionalData.AddAttachmentMessageProcessor

Comment: What is the format of the file?

Comment: I am passing a request from an xml file named SoapRequestInsert.xml to the Client flow as you can see the client flow has a file inbound endpoint that takes SoapRequestInsert.xml as request .. In log I can see it's entering into insertDataOperation() method of MainDataImpl but it is unable to get the iput data ... no errors are there but nothing happens and data is not getting inserted in DB ... I am using jdbcTemplate in Service to insert the data into DB

Comment: Does the `SoapRequestInsert.xml` file contain a full SOAP envelope like you show above or just a SOAP body, or something else?

Comment: Yes David.. it contains the same request I mentioned .. It contains full SOAP request including Envelope ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the file you are posting contains the whole SOAP envelope you can HTTP POST it as is:

`<flow name="ClientFlow" doc:name="ClientFlow">
 <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_Global" doc:name="File"  path="E:\backup\test">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="SoapRequestInsert.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>`

Note that you may need to add the SOAP action header, before the `http:outbound-endpoint`:

```
<set-property name="SOAPAction"
     value="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1/insertDataOperation" />
```

Comment: Wonderful .. I am getting to insert Data in DB .. But I have 2 questions here ... 1)You have removed CXF client .. is that means CXF client is not required anymore ??? and second question 2) set-property name="SOAPAction" is not working ... where do I need to place it ..do I need to paste it before http outbound ? I am asking because .. now I am planning to set SOAP action explicity

Comment: 1) You do not need CXF to simply POST an entity to a remote HTTP server. 2) What do you mean by "not working".

Comment: Whenever I am using set-property name="SOAPAction" value="insertDataOperation"  before http outbound I am getting an exception org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: The given SOAPAction insertDataOperation does not match an operation.

Comment: I copied the action `insertDataOperation` from your question, which seems to be wrong. The SOAP envelope has `insertDataRequest` so I think that's the value you need to use. Just be consistent.

Comment: Hi David ... The operation name is correct ... I have the operation insertDataOperation ... but strangely it is showing exception when I set it in set-property

Comment: Pls find the update question .. I have added WSDL there

Comment: OK so the action is `http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1/insertDataOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

The final working solution is as David suggested the flow and by setting SOAPAction before outbound endpoint :-

```
<set-property name="SOAPAction"
     value="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1/insertDataOperation" />
```